# Reading binary file into a struct using C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, binaryfiles

I have a problem (and I think it can be resolved easily, but it is driving me crazy). I have checked other posts, but I was not able to find the solution.

I would like to read a binary file into a struct using C++/CLI. The problem is that after reading it, some of the values do not fit with the correct ones. In the example below, all the struct fields are well read until "a" (included) (at around byte 100). From that field, the rest have wrong values. I know that they have wrong values and the source file is right, since I previously used python, and `FileStream` and `BinaryReader` from C++/CLI. However, I am not using them anymore, given that I would like to read the binary file into a struct.

In addition, in some cases I also have a value of -1 for variable "size" (size of the file), but not always. I am not sure if it could get a wrong value when the file is too big.

Therefore, my question if you can see something that I cannot, or I am doing something wrong.

```
struct LASheader
{
    unsigned short x;
    char y[16];
    unsigned char v1;
    unsigned char v2;
    char y1[68];
    unsigned short a;
    unsigned long b;
    unsigned long c;
    unsigned char z;
    unsigned short d;
    unsigned long e;
}

void main()
{    
    FILE *ptr = fopen("E:\\Pablo\\file.las", "rb");
    //I go at the end of the file to get the size
    fseek(ptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long long size = ftell(ptr);

    struct LASheader lasHeader;
    //I want an offset of 6 bytes
    fseek(ptr, 6, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&lasHeader, sizeof(lasHeader), 1, ptr);

    unsigned short a1 = lasHeader.a;
    unsigned long b1 = lasHeader.b;
    unsigned long c1 = lasHeader.c;
    unsigned short d1 = lasHeader.d;
    unsigned long e1 = lasHeader.e;
}
```

Thank you!

Pablo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things here. I'll tackle the direct problem first.

---

You didn't say how this binary format was being written, but I think it's an alignment issue.

Without a [`#pragma pack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) directive, `unsigned long b` will align to a 4-byte boundary. Struct members `x` through `a` are 90 bytes total, so two padding bytes are inserted between `a` and `b` so that `b` is aligned properly.

To fix the alignment, you can surround the struct with `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`.

---

Second, a more overall issue:

You called this C++/CLI code, and you tagged it C++/CLI, but you're not actually using any managed features in this code. Also, you said you have some C# code that works using `BinaryReader`, and `BinaryReader` works fine in C++/CLI, so you technically already had a C++/CLI solution in-hand.

If the rest of your C++/CLI project is this way (not using managed code), consider switching your project to C++, or perhaps splitting it. If your project is largely making use of managed code, then I would strongly consider using `BinaryReader` instead of `fopen` to read this data.

Comment: Thank you! It worked just using `#pragma pack(1)`.

The other problem I have is to get the file size when it is a huge file (e.g. 6720826368 bytes). I guess it is because `ftell()` returns a long variable, and this size is higher than the long maximum limit.
Do you know another way to get the size for huge files? And I would also have problems using `fseek()`, since it needs a long as parameter as well.

Comment: About the second thing you mentioned. I am using C++/CLI, since I am new in C++, and I think I just can use `System` from C++/CLI.
And I am not using `BinaryReader` anymore, since I do not know how to read the binary file using a struct or an array of structs, it is why I tried with `fread()`.
But new suggestions are very welcome. The only condition is that I am working with huge amount of data, and I would need the most optimized way.

Comment: I have replaced `fseek()` and `ftell()` with `_fseeki64()` and `_ftelli64()`, respectively, and it works. But as I said, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: If you're new to C++, please do yourself a favor and don't use C++/CLI. Adding the managed constructs onto the language if you don't need them just increases the complexity for the developer. In Visual Studio, make a "Win32" C++ project to create an unmanaged C++ project. C++/CLI should be used when you need it to provide a link between C++ and C# code, not just because you want to use to .Net library. (If you want to use the .Net library, use C#.)